# Tar is uninstalled, how is it possible to reinstall it?

Tags: 14.04, apt, package-management, tar

I was doing some stuff on my Ubuntu PC, when I did

```
sudo apt-get autoremove tar
```

and messed up my computer. I apparently wanted to reinstall tar, but instead removed it thinking I would install it after it is removed. This was a mistake and I regret doing it.

Now, I can hardly do anything with tar not installed in my computer. I can't install any packages using `apt-get`, neither can I install packages using `dpkg`. I tried downloading a `.deb` file of tar and installing it in my computer using `dpkg`, but as I said I couldn't do that either.

I can't install tar using `apt-get` either, so I couldn't figure out how to install tar in my computer again.

I tried searching on websites including AU, but couldn't find a solution to this.

How can you install tar without having tar installed in your computer? (solutions with apt-get, dpkg etc will not work) I'm on Ubuntu 14.04 LTS.

Comment: can you extract bz2 files?

Comment: You *might* be able to pull this one out of the fire using `busybox` - I think I'd try something like `sudo ln -s /bin/busybox /usr/local/bin/tar` and **then** try running `sudo apt-get install --reinstall tar`

Comment: @steeldriver outstandingly reasonable suggested fix.

Comment: @steeldriver smart idea!

Comment: Yes please post the complete error. It sounds like busybox tar *did* work - to the extent that it has given you a workaround for your immediate missing `tar` issue. Now we need to figure out what else is broken.

Comment: Sure - I suggest you remove the `/usr/local/bin/tar` symlink if you have not already done so (you may also need to run `hash -r tar` to ensure the shell finds `/bin/tar` after)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I solved the problem with some hacky workarounds, but it works. Might not be the best way to solve the problem though. I got the answer by following some parts of [@steeldriver's comment](https://askubuntu.com/questions/870297/tar-is-uninstalled-how-is-it-possible-to-reinstall-it?noredirect=1#comment1348877_870297) and adding some of my own.

---

First you need to download the [.deb file for tar](http://packages.ubuntu.com/trusty-updates/i386/tar/download).

Go to you Downloads folder, by using the command

```
cd ~/Downloads/
```

and then doing

```
ls | grep tar
```

to make sure the download succeeded. You should get an output similar to

```
tar_1.27.1-1ubuntu0.1_i386.deb
```

If not, you should try downloading again.

---

<sub>I'm going to use the name `mytar.deb` for the answer, but replace that with the real name of your `.deb` file</sub>

Now, you need to extract the contents of the `.deb` file *without* using tar.

First do

```
ar x mytar.deb
```

which [will extract the files from the archive](https://debian-handbook.info/browse/stable/packaging-system.html#sect.binary-package-structure) into the current directory. To list the files present, do

```
ar t mytar.deb
```

which will output something similar to

```
debian-binary
control.tar.gz
data.tar.xz
```

`data.tar.xz` contains the actual files which we need to copy. We cannot use `tar` to extract them because our current computer does not have the tar command.

First lets convert `data.tar.xz` to `data.tar`. To do this, do

```
xz -dc < data.tar.xz > data.tar
```

which should create a new file `data.tar`.

Now, we need to create a link to busybox as mentioned by @steeldriver in the comments. So do

```
sudo ln -s /bin/busybox /usr/local/bin/tar
```

to create a symlink.

Then, you basically are using busybox instead of tar. So if you use the command tar, it invokes busybox instead. Now do

```
mkdir temp
```

to create a dummy directory. Then

```
tar -xf data.tar -C temp/
```

to extract the `.tar` file and dump its contents in the directory `temp`. Change the working directory to `temp` by using

```
cd temp
```

Then do,

```
ls -pal
```

to get an output like

```
total 28
drwxrwxr-x  5 ashish ashish  4096 Jan 11 08:41 ./
drwxr-xr-x 23 ashish ashish 12288 Jan 11 08:41 ../
drwxr-xr-x  2 ashish ashish  4096 Jan 11 08:41 bin/
drwxr-xr-x  2 ashish ashish  4096 Jan 11 08:41 etc/
drwxr-xr-x  5 ashish ashish  4096 Jan 11 08:41 usr/
```

If you do not get the folders like `bin`, `etc`, and `usr`, you have made some mistake.

Now, you can just copy all the files in those folders to the actual destinations (`/bin/tar`, `/usr/local/bin/tar` etc), and then do

```
tar --help
```

If you get an output showing the commands of tar, it works!

Now do

```
sudo apt-get install --reinstall tar
```

which should reinstall tar. If it gives you an error saying to run `apt-get -f install`, do that and then reinstall tar, it worked for me on Ubuntu 14.04 LTS.

Comment: Remember to remove `/usr/local/bin/tar` afterwards so that `/usr/bin/tar` is actually `tar`. Also, if you're only using `busybox` to extract the files, you can just do `busybox tar -xf ...`

Answer (score 3):

You can run a live-cd of your ubuntu distro version to copy tar from live distro to your hard drive.

1. Boot from CD (or usb)
2. Mount your hard drive to /mnt : (if your hard drive is /dev/sdb1)

   ```
   mount /dev/sda1 /mnt
   ```
3. Copy /bin/tar to /mnt/bin/tar

   ```
   cp /bin/tar /mnt/bin/tar
   ```
4. If it's not enough, you can try to copy others tar related files.  You can list them with dpkg  :

   ```
   $ dpkg -L tar 
   /bin
   /bin/tar
   /usr
   /usr/sbin
   /usr/sbin/tarcat
   /usr/sbin/rmt-tar
   /usr/share
   /usr/share/doc
   /usr/share/doc/tar
   /usr/share/doc/tar/changelog.Debian.gz
   /usr/share/doc/tar/copyright
   /usr/share/doc/tar/NEWS.Debian.gz
   /usr/share/doc/tar/NEWS.gz
   /usr/share/doc/tar/README.Debian
   /usr/share/doc/tar/THANKS.gz
   /usr/share/doc/tar/AUTHORS
   /usr/share/man
   /usr/share/man/man8
   /usr/share/man/man8/rmt-tar.8.gz
   /usr/share/man/man1
   /usr/share/man/man1/tarcat.1.gz
   /usr/share/man/man1/tar.1.gz
   /usr/lib
   /usr/lib/tar
   /usr/lib/mime
   /usr/lib/mime/packages
   /usr/lib/mime/packages/tar
   /etc
   /etc/rmt
   ```