# I deleted tar and dpkg by mistake: Please Help

Tags: command-line, apt, package-management, dpkg, tar

Due to some tutorial that I followed wrongly, I am receiving this error when I try sudo apt-get upgrade. Please help.

```
dpkg: warning: 'tar' not found in PATH or not executable
dpkg: error: 1 expected program not found in PATH or not executable
Note: root's PATH should usually contain /usr/local/sbin, /usr/sbin and /sbin
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (2)
```

echo which tar
echo $PATH gives this output:

> paras@paras:/$ sudo echo $PATH
>
> /usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin:/usr/games

Comment: Welcome to AskUbuntu! Please [edit] the output of `echo $PATH` into your question. Thank you for helping us help you!

Comment: @ElderGeek I've updated my query, please tell me how to proceed.

Comment: Your own user's PATH (i.e. `echo $PATH`) is unlikely to be informative, since `dpkg` is being run via `sudo`. FWIW it looks like you didn't delete `dpkg` at least (since the message about `tar` comes from `dpkg`). Are you sure you deleted `tar`? What does `ls -l /bin/tar` say?

Comment: Since /bin is on your path and that's where tar lives @steeldriver is correct. The output will indicate whether it's missing, or permissions are off.

Comment: If you really have deleted tar, then you *can* re-install it from the appropriate downloaded `.deb` file - but it will need a bit of trickery. See for example [Tar is uninstalled, how is it possible to reinstall it?](https://askubuntu.com/a/870497/178692)

Comment: dpkg-deb: error: tar subprocess returned error exit status 1
dpkg: error processing archive /var/cache/apt/archives/bsdutils_1%3a2.31.1-0.4ubuntu3.4_amd64.deb (--unpack):
 dpkg-deb --control subprocess returned error exit status 2
Errors were encountered while processing:
 /var/cache/apt/archives/bsdutils_1%3a2.31.1-0.4ubuntu3.4_amd64.deb
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)

Comment: @ElderGeek after successfully reinstalling tar. I am now getting this error while doing sudo apt-get upgrade

Comment: @steeldriver ^^

Comment: @ParasRawat that sounds like it should be a separate question - I suggest mentioning the re-installed `tar` and adding a link to this question in case it turns out to be relevant. Also please mention what tutorial you were following originally.